# unable to pass data from js to jade in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cassandra, pug

I am reading a row from a table(emp) in cassandra.

[image]

I am trying to pass the result from js file to jade file to present the data on the user interface.

I have the js function as below

```
router.get('/cassandra', function (req, res)
{
client.connect(function(err){
    });

client.execute('SELECT * FROM monica.emp WHERE empid= 324;', function (err, result) {
var user = result.rows[0];
console.log("here is the user", user.empid, user.firstname);
res.render('cassandra',{"cassandra":user});
});
});
```

[image]

my log is reading the result. But i am unable to pass the same to the UI from the jade file.

Below is my Jade File

```
  extends layout

block content
  p Cassandra



    for i in cassandra


            .c=i.empid+" "+i.deptid
```

I am getting a display something like below

[image]

Can someone please help me with where I am going wrong over here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `user` is not an array. So just try `cassandra.empid` without a loop in the jade view

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
-for(var i in cassandra){
    .c=#{cassandra[i].empid}+" "+#{cassandra[i].deptid}
-}
```

Comment: Please describe why have posted this as answer? and how it solves the user problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a promise. Are you trying to render the template before the response comes back from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Your jade file should read

```
extends layout

block content
    p Cassandra

        #{cassandra.empid} #{cassandra.deptid}
```